# Menu parameters in Joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla-extensions

I create a menu link to view and the URL looks like:
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_example&view=homepage&layout=list.tpl&Itemid=154

And i want do add a parameter to a link that looks like:
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_example&view=homepage&layout=list.tpl&task=search&Itemid=154

I mean specifically this parameter "task=search".

What should I add to the xml file to create the link above.

My list.tpl.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
        <layout title="Latest List">
                <message>
                        Latest Listings
                </message>
        </layout>
        <state>
            <name>Latest</name>
            <description>Search form with latest listings</description>
            <url>

            </url>
            <advanced>
            </advanced>
    </state>

</metadata>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

The following will only work in Joomla 1.5 ...

```
<url>
    <param name="task" type="hidden" default="search" />
</url>
```

The equivalent of this in Joomla 1.6/1.7 is ...

```
<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request" label="Basic Parameters">
        <field name="task" type="hidden" default="search" />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

The defining parts being `name="request"` of both `<fields>` and `<fieldset>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<url addpath="/components/com_payplans/elements">
    <param name="task" type="hidden" default="taskValue" />
</url>
```